# Description of a TM

Tags: turing-machines, automata

What does it mean if I'm given a description of a TM? Does that mean, that since I'm given  I know exactly what M will accept/reject/loop?

Not sure exactly of what to think

Comment: I can't understand the second sentence of your question so I'm afraid I'm not sure to think, either. Did you read the definition of Turing machines, for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)?

Comment: I'm trying to ask if I'm given a <M> in a problem, what does that mean? Does that mean by the description I can figure out what it accepts/rejects/loops?

Comment: Have you learned a formal definition of the Turing machine? I think <M> would be defined in some way.

Answer (score 1):

A *description of a TM* is the Turing machine encoded under some fixed formal encoding. Think of it like the "source code" for the Turing machine.

In particular, the only information given to you is the definition of the Turing machine. Its properties are up to you to find out.